# UWP C# How To Auto Restart UWP App if it Crashes

Tags: uwp, crash, application-restart

I would like to find out if there is any way to auto restart UWP app if it crashes? I have my UWP app running on windows 10.
Please advise.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, UWP doesn't have a way to auto restart after it is crashed. When the app is crashed, the code will break.  A possible way is that you could create a win32 app that detects the process of the UWP app, when the process exits, launch the UWP app again.

Besides, I'd suggest handling the exception rather than restarting the app after it is crashed.

Comment: for now I am still finding ways to handle the exception. Meantime, I would like to find out if there is any reference for win32 app to detects the uwp app process. 
Could you please advise if there is any documentation which I can look into. Thanks.

Comment: @mylim I'm not very familiar with winapi, but here is one that might be able to help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51658214/detecting-a-process-crash-in-c-win32